# What brings you here? Why the subject"You" is used after brings?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, present-perfect

What brings you here? 
Why the subject "You"has been used after the verb "brings?

Comment: *You* is not the subject of the sentence *What brings you here?*. (On the other hand, *you* is the subject of this sentence: *Who/Whom do you bring here?*)

Answer (score 1):

This is an idiomatic phrase and means "Why did you come here?" rather than "What (bus, plane, car etc.) brought you here?".

There is a similar expression "Who brings you here?". This is less common and means "Who have you come to see?"

Comment: "Who brings you here?" isn't used that often, and would be most suitable at an event of some sort where there are numerous notable speakers, when you are an attendee and are asking another attendee who they have come to listen to. You wouldn't be asked this when attending a Doctor, or at the reception desk of a company, for example.